# Custom Field Query - Meta Value is Array

Tags: wp-query

I'm using a custom field query (or trying to) :

```
$args =  array(
    'post_type'     => 'pf_cookbook', 
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'key'           => 'pf_cookbook_recipes',
        'value'         => '5',
        'compare'       => 'NOT IN',
        'type'          => 'NUMERIC'
    ) 
);
```

However, the meta value to be compared is an array. The idea here is I am querying the DB to get the cookbooks which don't contain a certain recipe. The Recipes & Cookbooks are Custom Post Types. The Cookbooks have a meta key 'pf_cookbook_recipes' which I am storing an array of recipe IDs.

Maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`meta_query` needs to be an array of arrays - have a look at the code sample in the Codex again.

So, for your example:

```
$args =  array(
   'post_type'   => 'pf_cookbook', 
   'meta_query'  => array(
                       array(
                        'key'           => 'pf_cookbook_recipes',
                        'value'         => '5',
                        'compare'       => 'NOT IN',
                        'type'          => 'NUMERIC'
                        )
                    )
);
```

);

Comment: Thanks, my brain has gone to mush after 4 days off. Thanks, i'll mark as answered when I can.