# meta_query with meta values as serialize arrays

Tags: wp-query, metabox, meta-query

I'm working on a project in which I'm creating a custom post type and custom data entered via meta boxes associated with my custom post type. For whatever reason I decided to code the meta boxes in such a way that the inputs in each metabox are part of an array. For instance, I'm storing longitude and latitude:

```
<p> 
    <label for="latitude">Latitude:</label><br /> 
    <input type="text" id="latitude" name="coordinates[latitude]" class="full-width" value="" /> 
</p> 
<p>     
    <label for="longitude">Longitude:</label><br /> 
    <input type="text" id="longitude" name="coordinates[longitude]" class="full-width" value="" /> 
</p>
```

For whatever reason, I liked the idea of having a singular postmeta entry for each metabox. On the `save_post` hook, I save the data like so:

```
update_post_meta($post_id, '_coordinates', $_POST['coordinates']);
```

I did this because I have three metaboxes and I like just having 3 postmeta values for each post; however, I've now realized a potential issue with this. I may want to use WP_Query to only pull out certain posts based these meta values. For instance, I may want to get all posts that have latitude values above 50. If I had this data in the database individually, perhaps using the key `latitude`, I would do something like:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my-post-type',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'latitude',
            'value' => '50',
            'compare' => '>'
        )
    )
 );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Since I have the latitude as part of the `_coordinates` postmeta, this would not work.

So, my question is, is there a way to utilize `meta_query` to query a serialized array like I have in this scenario?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**No, it is not possible, and could even be dangerous.**

There is no reliable way to do this without encountering gotchas and pitfalls such as a search for `10` matching `100` or `210`, or matching the wrong sub-value etc. Such solutions are unreliable and have performance and security issues.

Serialised data is an attack vector, and a major performance issue.

I'll cover:

- Fixing it and making it queryable
- Why Can't You Query Inside Serialised Data?

  - Why `LIKE` isn't a solution
- A Note on Storing Records/Entities/Objects as Serialized Objects in Meta
- Security and Serialized Objects
- What to do If I have a List of IDs?
- What to do If I Have an Array of Named items?
- Sidestepping The Problem Entirely
- Conclusion

#### But What About `LIKE`?

You might see some well meaning questions that suggest using `LIKE` to achieve this. Does this not solve the problem? **This is not the solution, it is fools gold.**

There are several major problems:

- **false matches**, searching for `test` with `LIKE` will also match `test`, `testing`, `untested`, and other values
- there's no way to constrict this to sub-keys for arrays with keys or objects
- it's not possible to do sorting
- it's extremely slow and expensive

`LIKE` will only work for specific limited situations that are unrealistic, and carries a heavy performance penalty.

### Fixing It And Making It Queryable

I strongly recommend you unserialise your data and modify your save routine. Something similar to this should convert your data to the new format:

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'my-post-type',
    'meta_key' => '_coordinates',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
];
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // get the data
        $c = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_coordinates', true );

        // save it in the new format, separate post meta, taxonomy term etc
        add_post_meta( $post->ID, '_longitude', $c['longitude'] );
        add_post_meta( $post->ID, '_latitude', $c['latitude'] );

        // Optional: clean up the old post meta
        delete_post_meta( $post->ID, '_coordinates', $c );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Then you'll be able to query as you want with individual keys

If you need to store multiple longitudes, and multiple latitudes, you can store multiple post meta with the same name. Simply use the third parameter of `get_post_meta`, and it will return them all as an array

### Why Can't You Query Inside Serialised Data?

MySQL sees it as just a string, and can't break it apart into structured data. Breaking it apart into structured data is exactly what the code above does

You may be able to query for partial chunks of date, but this will be super unreliable, expensive, slow, and very fragile, with lots of edge cases. Serialised data isn't intended for SQL queries, and isn't formatted in a regular and constant way.

Aside from the costs of partial string searches, post meta queries are slow, and serialised data can change depending on things such as the length of contents, making searching incredibly expensive, if not impossible depending on the value you're searching for

### A Note on Storing Records/Entities/Objects as Serialized Objects in Meta

You might want to store a transaction record in post meta, or some other kind of data structure in user meta, then run into the problem above.

The solution here is not to break it out into individual post meta, but to realise it should never have been meta to begin with, but a custom post type. For example, a log or record can be a custom post type, with the original post as a parent, or joined via a taxonomy term

### Security and Serialized Objects

**Storing serialized PHP objects via the `serialize` function can be dangerous**, which is unfortunate as passing an object to WordPress will mean it gets serialised. This is because when the object is de-serialized, an object is created, and all its wake up methods and constructors get executed. This might not seem like a big deal until a user manages to sneak a carefully crafted input, leading to remote code execution when the data is read from the database and de-serialized by WordPress.

This can be avoided by using JSON instead, which also makes the queries easier, but it's much easier/faster to just store the data correctly and avoid structured serialized data to begin with.

### What If I have a List of IDs?

You might be tempted to give WP an array, or to turn it into a comma separated list, but you don't have to!

Post meta keys are not unique, you can store the same key multiple times, e.g.:

```php
$id = ...;
add_post_meta( $id, 'mylist', 1 );
add_post_meta( $id, 'mylist', 2 );
add_post_meta( $id, 'mylist', 3 );
add_post_meta( $id, 'mylist', 4 );
add_post_meta( $id, 'mylist', 5 );
add_post_meta( $id, 'mylist', 6 );
```

But how do I get the data back out? Have you ever noticed how calls to `get_post_meta` have a 3rd parameter that's always set to true? Set it to `false`:

```php
$mylist = get_post_meta( $id, 'mylist', false );
foreach ( $mylist as $number ) {
    echo '<p>' . esc_html( $number ) . '</p>;
}
```

### What If I Have an Array of Named items?

What if I wanted to store this data structure in a way that lets me query the fields?

```json
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "fizz": "buzz"
  "parent": {
    "child": "value"
  }
}
```

That's easy, split it up with prefixes:

```php
add_post_meta( $id, "tomsdata_foo", "bar" );
add_post_meta( $id, "tomsdata_fizz", "buzz" );
add_post_meta( $id, "tomsdata_parent_child", "value" );
```

And if you needed to loop over some of those values, use `get_post_meta( $id );` to grab all post meta and loop over the keys, e.g.:

```php
$all_meta = get_post_meta( $id );
$look_for = 'tomsdata_parent';
foreach ( $all_meta as $key => $value ) {
    if ( substr($string, 0, strlen($look_for)) !== $look_for ) {
        continue; // doesn't match, skip!
    }
    echo '<p>' . $key . ' = ' . $value . '</p>';
}
```

Which would output:

```html
<p>tomsdata_parent_child = value</p>
```

*Remember, when WP fetches a post it fetches all its post meta at the same time, so `get_post_meta` calls are super cheap and do not trigger extra database queries*

### Sidestepping The Problem Entirely

If you know you're going to need to search/query/filter on a sub-value, why not store an additional post meta with that value so you can search for it?

### Conclusion

**So you don't need to store structured data as a string in the database, and you shouldn't if you plan to search/query/filter on those values.**

It might be possible to use a regular expression and a `LIKE`, but this is **extremely unreliable**, doesn't work for most types of data, and very, very slow and heavy on the database. You also can't perform math on the results like you could if they were separate values

Comment: For people passing by, don't stop reading: more useful (and recent) answers are found below

Comment: What if I have an array of IDs to save - and they do not each represent a different key I could save them under such as 'latitude' etc., it's just one key for all (such as when saving relations etc.). What to do then? @rabni's solution?

Comment: You can store a key more than once, key value pairs are not unique. As for relations, that's what taxonomies are for, if you're using meta to map multiple things onto something, put them in a taxonomy term instead

Comment: Of course it is possible.
Yes, you need to be sure to have unique values, which is the whole nature of such postmeta. Usually, such serialised values stem from checkboxes that are arrays. Each checkbox of the set should have a unique value. And if not, they make sure its option (in php: the array key) is unique, so you can find that.

Later, the query is a Childs task compared to your solution presented:
```
'meta_query'     => array(
    array(
     'key'     => 'thekey',
     'value'   => 'thevalue',
     'compare' => 'LIKE',
     'type'    => 'CHAR',
    ),
   ),
```

Comment: @BedaSchmid that does not do what you think it does, if you had read my answer you'd see I addressed the `LIKE` clause and pointed out major flaws in it that prevent it being reliable and cause bugs. See the part titled _"What About LIKE?"_. I've edited my answer to move it higher up for people who don't read the whole answer as there have been a few over the years

Comment: @TomJNowell - of all those 4 reasons, only one is a serious issue and it is as in my comment elaborated avoidable. Slow? Yes. Every meta query is slow. Sorting by? Ok. I guess if you really need to query by that field you might be able to look over sorting by it. It is a bit weird anyway to sort by an array where multiple choices might be selected. 
It _is_ possible to query by such values and _it does not return inaccurate results, as long the serialised array has unique values, as I mention in my comment_

Answer (score 38):

I also run into this situation.
Here what i did:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my-post-type',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'latitude',
            'value' => sprintf(':"%s";', $value),
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
```

Hope this help

Comment: I really liked this solution. Unfortunately, this is not applicable when the `$value` is also an ID. In that case, i suggest to create to functions to add a character to each array element before saving the data and another function to remove the character before using the data. This wat, the serialized `i:2` index will not be confused with the `i:D2` of the "real" data. The meta query parameter should then become `'value' => sprintf(':"D%s";', $value),` and you will keep the correct functionality of this wonderful answer!

Comment: This solution is working for me

Comment: This also worked perfectly for me. Did have a mini panic when I saw the accepted solution though

Comment: @Erenor Paz, I just posted a solution which works well with both ID and Strings: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/299325/25264

Comment: using `LIKE` is a great and fast way to bring your server down (not to mention false positives) you better have a very good caching.

Comment: Note that with this solution, it will match any subvalue with that value. So if you look for a latitude of `5`, it will match longitudes of `5` too. This is less of an issue with this particular use case, but it's something to watch out for. It's also impossible to sort the results, and it's not possible to perform any logic/math such as fetch all values that are above or below a number

Answer (score 11):

You really are going to lose the ability to query your data in any efficient manner when serializing entries into the WP database.

The overall performance saving and gain you think you are achieving by serialization is not going to be noticeable to any major extent. You might obtain a slightly smaller database size but the cost of SQL transactions is going to be heavy if you ever query those fields and try to compare them in any useful, meaningful manner.

Instead, save serialization for data that you do not intend to query in that nature, but instead would only access in a passive fashion by the direct WP API call `get_post_meta()` - from that function you can unpack a serialized entry to access its array properties too.

In fact assigned the value of **true** as in;

`$meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'key', true );`

Will return the data as an array, accessible for you to iterate over as per normal.

You can focus on other database/site optimizations such as caching, CSS and JS minification and using such services as a CDN if you require. To name but a few.... WordPress Codex is a good starting point to uncover more on that topic: [**HERE**](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Optimization)

Answer (score 6):

I think there are 2 solutions that can try to solve the problem of results being stored as both String and Integers. However, it's important to say, as others pointed out, that it is not possible to guarantee the integrity of results stored as Integer, because as these values as stored as serialized arrays, the index and the values are stored exactly with the same pattern. Example:

```
array(37,87);
```

is stored as a serialized array, like this

```
a:2:{i:0;i:37;i:1;i:87;}
```

Note the `i:0` as the first position of the array and `i:37` as the first value. The pattern is the same. But let's go to the solutions

---

**1) REGEXP Solution**

This solution works for me regardless of the meta value being saved as string or number / id. However it uses `REGEXP`, which is not so fast as using `LIKE`

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my-post-type',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'latitude',
            'value' => '\;i\:' . $value . '\;|\"' . $value . '\";',
            'compare' => 'REGEXP'
        )
    )
);
```

**2) LIKE Solution**

I'm not sure about the performance difference but this is a solution that uses `LIKE` and also works for both number and strings

```
 $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'my-post-type',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'latitude',
                'value' => sprintf(':"%s";', $value),
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'latitude',
                'value' => sprintf(';i:%d;', $value),
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: `REGEXP` is nice in certain situations, but if you can use `LIKE`, I think it's the preferable method. An old link, but still quite useful, in my opinion: https://thingsilearn.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/mysql-query-speed-regexp-vs-like/ :-)

Comment: @ErenorPaz You are right. `LIKE` is faster. But this is a solution that works for both strings and numbers

Comment: Yes..so, the answer is (as always): depending on the situation, if you can use "LIKE"; it's preferable, otherwise REGEXP will do as well :-)

Comment: @ErenorPaz, I edited my answer adding a new solution that uses `LIKE` but works for both numbers and strings. I'm not sure about the performance because it has to compare the results using `OR`

Comment: Exactly !!! which i need to get result same like this....

Thanks Man!!!

Answer (score 3):

I've just dealed with serialized fields and could query them.
Not using the meta_query but using a SQL query.

```
global $wpdb; 

$search = serialize('latitude').serialize(50);

$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT `post_id`
FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE `post_id` IN (SELECT `ID` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = 'my-post-type')
AND `meta_key` = '_coordinates'
AND `meta_value` LIKE '%s'",'%'.$search.'%');

$ids = $wpdb->get_col($query);

$args = array(
    'post__in' => $ids
    'post_type' => 'team' //add the type because the default will be 'post'
);

$posts = get_posts($args);
```

The query first searches for post with the matching post_type so the amount of wp_postmeta records will be less to filter.
Then i've added a where statement to reduce the rows further by  filtering on `meta_key`

The IDs end up nicely in an array as needed for get_posts.

PS. MySQL v5.6 or higher is needed for good subquery performance

Answer (score 3):

A simple hack to this situation is to use `LIKE` compare with serialised format (length with type and value itself) as below:

```php
$id = 123; // id to check from serialised data.
//(assuming the numbers stored as string. In my case it was.)

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'meta_key_to_check_from',
            'value' => 's:' . strlen($id) . ':"' . $id . '";',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

If custom taxonomy to search:

```php
$id = 123; // id to check into the serialised data.
//(assuming the numbers stored as string. In my case it was.)

$args = array(
    'hide_empty' => false, // also retrieve terms which are not used yet
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'meta_key_to_check_from',
            'value' => 's:' . strlen($id) . ':"' . $id . '";',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    ),
    'taxonomy' => 'custom_taxonomy'
);

$terms = get_terms( $args );
```

Comment: I would say this example answers the question directly and is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This exactly solves the issue, best answer here!

Answer (score 2):

This example really helped me. It's specifically for S2Members plugin (which serializes user metadata). But it allows you to query a portion of a serialized array within the meta_key.

It works by using the MySQL REGEXP function.

[Here](http://www.primothemes.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=15658) is the source

Here is the code that queries all users living in the US. I easily modified it to query one of my custom registration fields and had it working in no time.

```
  <?php
global $wpdb;
$users = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT `user_id` as `ID` FROM `" . $wpdb->usermeta . 
          "` WHERE `meta_key` = '" . $wpdb->prefix . "s2member_custom_fields' AND 
           `meta_value` REGEXP '.*\"country_code\";s:[0-9]+:\"US\".*'");
if (is_array ($users) && count ($users) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($users as $user)
            {
                $user = /* Get full User object now. */ new WP_User ($user->ID);
                print_r($user); /* Get a full list of properties when/if debugging. */
            }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the only thing that worked when I was trying to get serialised data from a third party plugin.

Answer (score 0):

After reading a bunch of tips for running a `WP_Query` filtering by serialized arrays, here's how I finally did it: by creating an array of comma separated values using implode in conjunction with a `$wpdb` custom SQL query utilizing `FIND_IN_SET` to search the comma separated list for the requested value.

*(this is similar to Tomas's answer, but its a bit less performance intensive for the SQL query)*

**1. In functions.php:**

In your functions.php file (or wherever you're setting up the meta box) in the `yourname_save_post()` function use

```
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'checkboxArray', implode(",", $checkboxArray)); //adding the implode
```

to create the array containing comma separated values.

You'll also want to change your output variable in the `yourname_post_meta()` admin meta box construction function to

```
$checkboxArray = explode(",", get_post_custom($post->ID)["checkboxArray"][0]); //adding the explode
```

**2. In the template PHP file:**

Test: if you run a `get_post_meta( $id );` you should see `checkboxArray` as an array containing your comma separated values instead of a serialized array.

*Now, we build our custom SQL query using `$wpdb`.*

```
global $wpdb;

$search = $post->ID;

$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts
          WHERE FIND_IN_SET( $search, (
              SELECT wp_postmeta.meta_value FROM wp_postmeta
              WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'blogLocations'
              AND wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID )
          )
          AND ( wp_posts.post_type = 'post' )
          AND ( wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' );";

$posts = $wpdb->get_results($query);

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    //your post content here
}
```

Notice the `FIND_IN_SET`, that's where the magic happens.

Now... since I'm using `SELECT *` this returns *all the post data* and within the `foreach` you can echo out what you want from that (do a `print_r($posts);` if you don't know what's included. It doesn't set up "the loop" for you (I prefer it this way), but it can easily be modified to set up the loop if you prefer (take a look at `setup_postdata($post);` in the codex, you'll probably need to change `SELECT *` to select only post ID's and `$wpdb->get_results` to the correct `$wpdb` type -- see the codex for `$wpdb` also for information on *that* subject).

Whelp, it took a bit of effort, but since `wp_query` doesn't support doing `'compare' => 'IN'` serialized or comma separated values this shim is your best option!

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `like` comparison operator in your meta query, it should work fine to look inside a serialized array.

```
$wp_user_search = new WP_User_Query(array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'wp_capabilities',
            'value'   => 'subscriber',
            'compare' => 'not like'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

results in:

```
[query_where] => WHERE 1=1 AND (
  ( wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' 
  AND CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value AS CHAR) NOT LIKE '%subscriber%' )
```

Answer (score 0):

If my meta data is array type, i'm use this method for query by meta:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'fotobank',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                   'key' => 'collections',
                   'value' => ':"'.$post->ID.'";',
                   'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
     )
);
$fotos = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: This could lead to unwanted results when a post ID has the same value as the id of the serialized string

Answer (score 0):

I got curious about the answers above, where the `meta_query` targeted the key `latitude` instead of `_coordinates`. Had to go and test if it really was possible in meta queries to target a specific key inside a serialized array. :)

That obviously wasn't the case.

**So, note that the correct key to target is `_coordinates` instead of `latitude`.**

> ```
> $args = array(
>      'post_type' => 'my-post-type',
>      'meta_query' => array(
>          array(
>              'key' => '_coordinates',
>              'value' => sprintf(':"%s";', $value),
>              'compare' => 'LIKE'
>          )
>      )
>  );
> ```

**NOTES:**

1. This approach makes it only possible to target exact matches. So things like *all latitudes greater than 50* are not possible.
2. To include substring matches, one could use `'value' => sprintf(':"%%%s%%";', $value),`. (haven't tested)

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the value with `%` to query the serialized value:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my-post-type',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'latitude',
            'value' => '%' . 50 . '%',
            'compare' => '>'
        )
    )
 );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same question. Maybe you need the 'type' parameter? Check out this related question: 
[Custom Field Query - Meta Value is Array](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15622/custom-field-query-meta-value-is-array)

Perhaps try:

```
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my-post-type',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'latitude',
            'value' => '50',
            'compare' => '>',
            'type' => 'numeric'
        )
    )
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this isn't quite what I'm after. The problem is that the value I'm trying to match is a part of an array that is serialized within the database.

Comment: Yea, you're right. I tried this this morning and it didn't work for me either.

I have the same issue. Storing a value of a meta key as an array. I'm starting to think this can't be done and I might instead have to store them as separate meta fields with the same name...and just manage the deleting/updating of them properly.

Comment: @user4356...that's exactly what I'm going to do. I was hoping to cut down on the number of rows that I would insert for each post, but I guess that's not possible.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into something similar while using the Magic Fields plugin. This might do the trick

```
$values_serialized = serialize(array('50'));
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my-post-type',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'latitude',
            'value' => $values_serialized,
            'compare' => '>'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I think this is as close as one can get, but it won't actually work because comparing a serialized array to another serialized array doesn't made sense unless I was looking for an exact match.

Comment: Then this shouldn't be marked as the correct answer and it is irresponsible of you to do so. The correct answer thus would be 'No, it's not possible'

Comment: Agree, also WP handles serialization for you, `serialize()` is not required in this instance...

Comment: Actually @seth-stevenson answer is great when doing exactly what he said, using "Magic Fields" plugin. As that plugin serializes certain data type by default, this is the best way to do an EXACT match.

Comment: @TomJNowell Done! Just took me 5 months ;)