# Querying meta values within an array

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, wp-query, post-meta, meta-query

Okay so I'm using the relationship field from Advanced Custom Fields against a custom post type. The relationship lists countries, when these are saved they are within a serialised array:

```
[country] => Array
    (
        [0] => a:2:{i:0;s:2:"19";i:1;s:2:"72";}
    )

[_country] => Array
    (
        [0] => field_5049ccf3aac29
    )
```

I want to query the custom post type by a single country from within this serialised array, but it's not in a very good format for me to do so.

In SQL I'd be tempted to do a `LIKE` but that's neither ideal or available via `WP_Query`

Any ideas on how I can achieve this? I guess I could do a bit of custom SQL to return all post IDs for this CPT where the country has the country ID I'm after, I'm just hoping I'm missing a very obvious / cleaner solution.

**Edit 1**

So I've got it working using the following code, but it's not ideal:

```
    <?php

        $query = new WP_Query(
            array(
                'post_type'     => 'some_post_type',
                'meta_query'    => array(
                    array(
                        'key'       => 'country',
                        'compare'   => 'LIKE',
                        'value'     => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"'
                    )
                )
            )
        );

    ?>
```

This approach I mentioned before backed up by [this similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25945/can-serialized-arrays-in-db-be-matched-against-serialized-arrays-with-meta-query), again, not ideal but if anyone knows of a better solution I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, as suggested in my edit I've had to use the following `meta_query` array to query the posts:

```
'meta_query'    => array(
    array(
        'key'       => 'country',
        'compare'   => 'LIKE',
        'value'     => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"'
    )
)
```