# Using get_posts to get posts based on a checkbox value with Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, get-posts

I have a custom post type, "Jobs".

These jobs have an ACF checkbox field, "city". "Jobs" can have more than one "city," so the jobs returned have meta values look something like this:

```
[city] => Array
    (
        [0] => Austin
    ) 


[city] => Array
    (
        [0] => [Austin]
        [1] => [Boulder]
    )

[city] => Array
    (
        [0] => [Seattle]
        [1] => [Portland]
        [2] => [Boulder]
    )
```

I need to write a get_posts query so that I can return only jobs that match a single city.

However, I can't figure out what my arguments need to look like, since I need to match the value of "meta_value" is an array.

Here's my code, can you guys help?

```
function get_city_jobs() {
    $args = array( 
        'post_type'     =>  'careers_post_type', 
        'numberposts'   =>  -1,
        'meta_key'      =>  'city',
        'meta_value'    =>  'Boulder',
        'meta_compare'  =>  'LIKE'
    );

    $jobs = get_posts($args);

    foreach ($jobs as $job) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r( get_fields($job->ID));
        echo "</pre>";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the answer here:

[WP Query post meta value](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168770/wp-query-post-meta-value)

Turns out you have to use the `serialize` php function due to how wordpress stores arrays in the database.

```
function get_city_jobs() {

    $city = ($_GET['city']);
    $city = trim(ucfirst($city));

    $args = array( 
        'post_type'     =>  'careers_post_type', 
        'numberposts'   =>  -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'city',
                'value' => serialize($city),
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    );

    return get_posts($args);

}
```

Comment: Does this also work if a job has multiple cities?

Comment: @kero yes it does -- it pulls jobs regardless the size of the `cities[]` array.