# WP_Query Posts by Metadata from Option Tree

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, meta-query, plugin-option-tree

I am doing a `WP_Query` trying to filter out the posts by Metadata.

```
    $args = array(
      'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1,
      'post_type' => 'post_projects',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => $nr_posts,
      'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
          'key' => 'wpl_goal_amount',
          'value' => 100,
          'compare' => '!=',
        ),
        array(
          'key' => 'wpl_location',
          'value' => 'Europe',
          'compare' => '=',
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I am testing this out with two posts. One of them has "Europe" in it's array of locations, but whenever I run this, it doesn't come up with anything.

QUESTION UPDATE:

I am using Option Tree to save the Meta-data, and as mentioned in a previous answer, it stores serialized the post meta-data (by Wordpress' default), and in combination with that and another post, I found that there are two ways to query the serialized data. The first is more convenient, but more of a jerry-rig, and the second is more proper, but difficult:

1. The easier:

   ```
       array(
         'key' => 'wpl_location',
         'value' => '"' . $my_value . '"',
         'compare' => 'LIKE'
       ),
   ```
2. Compared to the better but more difficult:

   ```
      array(
         'key' => 'wpl_location',
         'value' => serialize(array(3 => 'Europe')),
         'compare' => 'LIKE'
       ),
   ```

I believe the second method would require me to have a (near) identical serialized array as the database, which would not work in the long-term for the system that I am creating, because it will need to match one out of many items in the array.

My updated question:

Should I continue down this path and use the first method, or do I need to dump Option Tree and figure out a way to add the meta-data to the posts in unserialized form so that it can be queried?

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the 'meta_key' arg here:

```
$args = array(
      'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1,
      'meta_key'   => 'wpl_location', // here
      'post_type' => 'post_projects',
      'meta_query' => array(
        array(
          'key' => 'wpl_location',
          'value' => 'Europe',
          'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
      ),
    );
```

source:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query (about three quarters down the page).

Comment: I believe 'key' is used instead of 'meta_key', when 'meta_query' is used with an Array of Array(s) are used.

Comment: agree with you:  have you given the 'compare' => '=',  a shot?  I believe the 'IN' is for multiple meta_query args.

Comment: Yes, my full function actually has a compare with multiple arrays here, but I put this function up as a simplified one. But anyways, I tried both the ways you mentioned.

Comment: then you may have to go all the way to just the meta_query itself:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query  then add that into your WP_Query( $args )

Comment: I changed the $args to the full one that I currently have. It'll get bigger than that, but it shows why the arrays are needed for 'meta_query'

Comment: if you change 'posts_per_page' => -1,  do you get all results?  or any?

Comment: Right now, I have two posts in the 'post_projects' 'post_type', the one with 'wpl_location' => 'Europe' also has 'wpl_goal_amount' => '100', so it always shows the first post, and if I can get the condition to 'wpl_location' to work, it will also pull the second post.

Answer (score 0):

If you're saving an array into Metadata it becomes [Serialized](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/doc/serialized-data/). This makes it pretty difficult to query on, maybe try using wildcard:

```
$args = array(
    'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1,
    'post_type'  => 'post_projects',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'wpl_location',
            'value'   => '%Europe%',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),
);
```

This will search the serialized data for anything that looks like "Europe".

Comment: Negative, but it is supposed to still be able to be done with serialized data, because the get_post_meta() function will actually give an unserialized array back if $single is set to 'true'.

Comment: @lawdawg [`get_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) **does** but [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) **does not**. `WP_Query` does not use `get_post_meta()` in any way, just plain ole' SQL. You may need to break that out of an array and save it as a normal string.

Comment: Oh yeah, I wasn't thinking about that. But anyways, I tried using that method and still didn't work.

Comment: I'm thinking this might answer our question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16709/meta-query-with-meta-values-as-serialize-arrays

Comment: @lawdawg Yeah, if you need to do any kind of `post_meta` filtering it's usually advised that you save that data separated as a string instead of serialized with your other data.