# How to do a sql like query on serialized data of user meta data

Tags: query, user-meta, oop

As long I don't need to do a query with the data of all users, storing data like the zip code or city in the meta data as an serialized object works fine. But now I have to do a lot of different selects concerning users meta data, f.i. "select all users which are living in London". How can I do such a query in WordPress if CITY is not a single field in a table, but part of a bunch of serialized data in one field in the wp_usermeta table. I assume there is not an easy way to do this.

So my question, **how to manage data that should be available as property of an object and could also be used in a query** like mentioned above.

Comment: You should be storing each field as a separate piece of user meta, not as a serialised object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [meta\_query with meta values as serialize arrays](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16709/meta-query-with-meta-values-as-serialize-arrays)

Comment: @JacobPeattie I know this, but how to get the data as object, if all properties stored in different fields.