# Fetch Record based on meta key dates

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, post-meta, query-posts, meta-query

I want to write a query which fetches the data based on my meta key added. Meta key name is 'repeater'.

This is my POST META.

Serialized:

```
a:3:{i:0;a:3:{s:9:"postdates";s:10:"2021-02-02";s:12:"postplatform";a:1:{i:0;s:3:"3DS";}s:10:"postregion";a:2:{i:0;s:2:"EU";i:1;s:2:"JP";}}i:1;a:3:{s:9:"postdates";s:10:"2021-02-03";s:12:"postplatform";a:2:{i:0;s:3:"3DS";i:1;s:2:"DS";}s:10:"postregion";a:2:{i:0;s:2:"EU";i:1;s:2:"JP";}}i:2;a:3:{s:9:"postdates";s:10:"2021-02-04";s:12:"postplatform";a:3:{i:0;s:3:"3DS";i:1;s:2:"DS";i:2;s:27:"MAC, Linux, Mobile And More";}s:10:"postregion";a:3:{i:0;s:2:"EU";i:1;s:2:"JP";i:2;s:2:"NA";}}}
```

Unserialized:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [postdates] => 2021-02-02
            [postplatform] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3DS
                )

            [postregion] => Array
                (
                    [0] => EU
                    [1] => JP
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [postdates] => 2021-02-03
            [postplatform] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3DS
                    [1] => DS
                )

            [postregion] => Array
                (
                    [0] => EU
                    [1] => JP
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [postdates] => 2021-02-04
            [postplatform] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3DS
                    [1] => DS
                    [2] => MAC, Linux, Mobile And More
                )

            [postregion] => Array
                (
                    [0] => EU
                    [1] => JP
                    [2] => NA
                )

        )

)
```

Now, I want to fetch the POST if postdates is today/ specific dates.

Thanks,
Ali

Comment: You can't query serialized data that way. You will need to structure your data differently.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [meta\_query with meta values as serialize arrays](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16709/meta-query-with-meta-values-as-serialize-arrays)

Comment: @JacobPeattie Can you please let me know how can I structure that data ?

Comment: I don't know enough about your data to know what's appropriate, but any meta value that you want to query by needs its own key. It _looks_ like the dates should be their own key, and the regions and platforms should be taxonomies.

Comment: You can't store the data in a single post meta, it has to be multiple separate values for each piece of data. Are you using an ACF repeater field? You can't query sub-values of serialized data

Comment: @TomJNowell I am not using ACF. I have created custom coding for this and I am saving the data in the format mentioned in my question. Now, I want to fetch based on the dates.

Comment: I see, that format can't be queried, I left an answer below. Post meta values need to be primitive values such as strings or numbers if you want to query them, not arrays or objects. What you want cannot be done while you are using arrays and objects in post meta

Answer (score 0):

**This is not possible, you cannot query sub-values of serialised/structured data in post meta values.**

To fix this, you need to store the dates you want to query/filter by as separate post meta key/value pairs. Values need to be string/number/boolean whole values to be queried this way. They cannot be complex structures or sub-strings, such as JSON, arrays, objects

Also note that *saving* an array or object is a security risk. This is because you can't save an array/object so WordPress uses PHP's `serialize` function, turning it into a string. This exposes you to object deserialisation attacks.